# Elasticsearch multi data path disk full

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a 500gb hard drive divided between os and elasticsearch data, being almost full I added a second 1Tb hard drive and added it as a second drive in the elasticsearch.yml

(ex:  `file.data: /els, /var/lib/elasticsearch`).

Through kiabna I can see that now the space is actually 1.5TB but every time I send a file this is saved in the usual hdd left the 1TB empty. 
can someone help me?

version of elasticsearch 6.6.1

[image]

Comment: new hdd have elasticsearch permission?

Comment: yes, because once the service has restarted, I found a folder with the name node inside it

Comment: do you run elasticsearch on linux? please ls -al /els  and  /var/lib/elasticsearch

Comment: what is the watermark and what percent of 500 HDD is full?

Comment: what did you mean by sending new files? did you mean new documents or new indices? because elastic use previously opened indices to index new documents.  you can delete previously indices and check where the new indices will be created?

Comment: the 500gb it's 94% full, I loaded the screen with its commands. i send the new document on the same index

Comment: the index is loaded on 500GB HDD. and elastic does not build another shard for this index. you should create a new index and send the data to new index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you send document to an old index, than that old index is not moved to the new path and stays on the old hdd. Using multiple paths, elasticsearch does not relocate shards where there is some space.

For further information, see the following [docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.6/path-settings.html):

> The path.data settings can be set to multiple paths, in which case all paths will be used to store data (although the files belonging to a single shard will all be stored on the same data path):

If you want to extend the current path, using new hdd, you can use something like  [Logical Volume Management](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Lvm). It is an abstraction of drives, so you can attach many real disk drives to a single logical drive.